# Swift Evaluate Javascript

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, wkwebview, javascriptcore

I am using JavaScript in my app.  It works when the web page is loaded in `viewDidLoad`, but not when it is loaded at the same time as the webView.  I have tried using `webView` with `didFinish`, but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?  Here is my code:

```
self.webby.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!))
                    self.webby.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"exampleID\").textContent;") { result, error in
                        print(error)
                        print(result)
                        if let result = result {
                            var t = String(describing: result)
                            str = t
                        }
                        }
```

Comment: is this little fellow (`webby`) an instance of `WKWebView` by any chance?

Comment: @holex Yes it is.

Comment: so... why don't you just set the `webby.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true`, maybe? (however it is supposed to be `true` by default)

Comment: @holex It works when the webView is loaded before it is called, but I need to make it run once the site loaded.